# A closed Banach subspace of a reflexive Banach space is also reflexive.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

Let $E$ be a reflexive Banach space and $B \subset E$ be a closed Banach subspace. I'm trying to show that $B$ is also a reflexive space. To this end, we can take $(x_n)_n \subset B$ a bounded sequence and show that $(x_n)_n$ has a subsequence that converges weakly. If $\ell \in B^*$, then $\ell$ can be extended to $\tilde{\ell} \in E^*$ such that $\tilde{\ell}|_{B} = \ell$ and therefore, there exists $x \in E$ with $x_{n_k} \rightharpoonup x$ for $(x_{n_k})_k \subset (x_n)_n$. But now I do not really know how to conclude that $x \in B$. Is it the right way to do that ? Does anyone know how to conclude ?

Comment: $x\in B$ follows from the convexity of $B$: A closed and convex subset of a normed space is weakly sequentially closed. This also follows from Hahn-Banach (separation version).

Comment: Do you know where can I find a proof of such a result ?

Comment: This is simple. Let $x_n\in C$, where $C\subset X$ is convex and closed and assume that $x_n\to x$ weakly. Choose any point $z\notin C$. Then by Hahn-Banach there exists a linear functional $\ell\in X^*$  such that $Re(\ell(z))\le a < b\le Re(\ell(y))$ for all $y\in C$. Since $x_n\in C$, we have $Re(\ell(x_n))\ge b$ and hence also $Re(\ell(x)) =  \lim Re(\ell(x_n))\ge b$ and therefore $x\in C$.